# How to add tags to the end of a CSV file based on data store in folders?

Tags: bash, csv

I have a CSV file, formatted like this:

```
0001 @ word @ some information @ other information @
```

The last column is left empty. I want to tag each line and put the tags in the last column.

I also have a directory, filled with plain text files containing nothing more than lists of words (1 per line). The filename of each list is identical to the tag I want to apply.

Lists/
Lists/fruit1
Lists/fruit2
Lists/vegetables1
Lists/vegetables2

How can I add the name of the every file which contains an exact match for the word in column 2 of the CSV to the end of the CSV? For e.g.:

A line in the CSV is like this, and the word "banana" appears in both of the lists in `fruit1` and `fruit2`.

```
0004 @ banana @ some information @ other information @
```

The line above would have those two file names added to the last column of the CSV:

```
0004 @ banana @ some information @ other information @ fruit1 fruit2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using a loop to read each line. Extract the second field using `cut`, and then use `grep` to find the files containing this field. Then `echo` out your results.

This is shown below:

```
while read line
do
    word=$(cut -d@ -f2 <<< "$line")
    results=( $(grep -l $word Lists/*) )
    echo "$line ${results[@]##*/}"
done < input.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

If the word files fit in memory, one solution for this would be to read the contents of all of them and map them to a dictionary where the keys are the tags to apply and the values are the set of words for those tags:

```
tags = {}
for filename in filenames:
    with open(filename) as f:
        tags[filename] = {line.strip() for line in f}
```

After that, the input csv file can be read and for each line, the word column can be checked to verify if it's included in any tag and if that's the case, add the tag to the desired column. Once the tag column is created, the result if written to an output csv file that contains the same data together with the new tag column:

```
import csv

word_column_number = 1
tags_column_number = 4

reader = csv.reader(open(input_csv), delimiter='@')
writer = csv.writer(open(output_csv, 'w'), delimiter='@')
for row in reader:
    word_column = row[word_column_number].strip()
    tag_column = [name for name, words in tags.iteritems()
                  if word_column in words]
    row[tags_column_number] = ' {0}'.format(' '.join(tag_column))
    writer.writerow(row)
```

Comment: Sorry, I mistakenly assumed that the question was tagged with python. Anyway, if you're willing to give it a try, this should work for you.

Answer (score 1):

This creates a `sed` script from the files in Lists/ and runs it on the csv file:

```
(cd ./Lists;
 for file in * ; do
     sed 's%^%/^[^@]*@ %;
          s%$% @/s/$/ '$file'/%' $file
 done) | sed -f- file.csv
```